# UNIQUE constraint failed - Django

Tags: django, debugging, django-models

I am unable to solve this problem. I have seen the similar queries posted but none of the answers helped.

**my Models:**

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), max_length=254, unique=True)
    contact_number = models.IntegerField(_('contact number'), validators=RegexValidator(r'^\+?1?\d{9,10}$'), unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    ....
```

On migration the error that appears:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: user_profile_myuser.contact_number
```

**Update:**

My Traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 63, in execute
    return super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 183, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
  File "/home/surajit/website/PubNet/user_profile/manager.py", line 31, in create_superuser
    **extra_fields)
  File "/home/surajit/website/PubNet/user_profile/manager.py", line 22, in _create_user
    user.save(using=self._db)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 80, in save
    super(AbstractBaseUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 806, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 836, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 922, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 961, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 1060, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1099, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 328, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: user_profile_myuser.contact_number
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,10}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'")
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], blank=True unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: make null and blank False and try and do  remember to remove the old migrations files before makemigratiosn

Comment: yes. Now the migration worked. but now I am getting error while creating superuser. Please check the traceback.

Comment: that is a different question, you need to post it separately

Comment: Ok. Will do that. Thanks @Exprator. :)